# I am UK resident with Indian passport traveling to Greece. Can I book Schengen visa appointment in Edinburgh instead of London?

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, greece, uk-residents

I am UK resident with Indian passport traveling to Greece. Can I book Schengen visa appointment in Edinburgh instead of London because there are no appointments available in London?

Comment: Why would you not be able to? Have you tried asking them? https://visa.vfsglobal.com/gbr/en/aut/contact-us